# Nested with - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'

Tags: sql-server

**With inside with**

This is ok

```
    WITH CS AS (
      SELECT      'ab' as a
    )
    SELECT * from cs
```

http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/revision/138658/170321/comment-partition-by-question

But, as soon as I wrap it with a second `with`,

```
with PS as (
        WITH CS AS (
          SELECT      'ab' as a
        )
        SELECT * from cs
        ) select * from PS
```

I get this error,

`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.  If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon. Incorrect syntax near ')'.`

**With inside select**

The following is ok

```
select ab.a from (
  select a from (SELECT 'ab' as a) b
            ) ab
```

This is also runs

```
  with cs as (SELECT 'ab' as a)
  select a from cs
```

But, wrapping expression with another select, as [this one proposes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4630000/1083704),

```
  select a from (
    with cs as (SELECT 'ab' as a)
    select a from cs
  ) ab
```

fails again with the same error.

I do it in data.stackexchange and they report that they use MSSQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> Specifying more than one WITH clause in a CTE is not allowed. For
>   example, if a CTE_query_definition contains a subquery, that subquery
>   cannot contain a nested WITH clause that defines another CTE.

Thus,

```
with PS as (
    WITH CS AS (
      SELECT      'ab' as a
    )
    SELECT * from cs
    ) select * from PS
```

gives you error. You can define multiple CTEs though :

```
WITH CS AS (SELECT 'ab' as a),
PS as (SELECT * from cs) 
select * from PS
```

Comment: Oops, sorry my bad... fixing. Second `WITH` is redundant. It should work now .. Check updated answer